# Stripe.h file not found in xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the Stripe SDK in my iOS App but there seems to be a problem. Whenever I try to import it like this:

```
#import "Stripe.h"
```

I get the following error:

Stripe.h file not found
But I have the file as shown in the picture attached.

[image: error: Stripe.h file not found]

Answer (score 2):

Since Stripe is a framework, you need to import like this.

```
    #import <Stripe/Stripe.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Objective-C –> Swift Bridging Header you have to import the Objective-C file like the following:

```
#import "Stripe.h"
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I did do that. It didn't work :/      Also, I do get a "Failed to import bridging header" error, if that's what might be causing the problem to?

Comment: Weird. Does it give you any other error / error description?